# i dont know what wrong with my solution, i cant write the a[2]. It exits at the end of the first while loop

Tags: arrays, c, input, while-loop

```
void Nhap_mang(int a[], int n){
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        
        int status;char junk;
        printf("\nEnter a number %d : ",i+1);status = scanf("%d", a[i]);
        while(status < 1){                   
            printf("\nwrong input, do it again!");
            scanf("%c", &junk);
            printf("\nEnter a number: ");
            status = scanf("%d", a[i]);
        }  
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", a[i])` --> `scanf("%d", &a[i])`, but there are other issues, too.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? What value is being passed to a[] and n in Nhap_mang()?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `status` variable to 0 (or < 1) on every (outer) loop iteration. Failing to do so will result you in having a garbage `status` value on the first iteration, and if you're lucky it's < 1, after which you'll use the stale value on the next iteration so it never enters the inner loop again.